# Decrypt file with openPGP using groovy

Tags: encryption, groovy, openpgp

I want to write a script in groovy to decrypt files using openPGP. I tried to find a library that I could use for this task but was unsuccessful. Is there a source I might have omitted during my search or I need to go some alternative way that you would recommend.

My idea with script is to be executed every time before the file processing needs to start. It seems as a relatively simple task, but I can't find this library.